# Changing the int and string from a string

Tags: python, string, function, formatting, integer

The `format_address` function separates out parts of the address string into new strings: `house_number` and `street_name`, and returns: `"house number X on street named Y"`.

The format of the input string is: numeric house number, followed by the street name which may contain numbers, but never by themselves, and could be several words long. For example, `"123 Main Street"`, `"1001 1st Ave"`, or `"55 North Center Drive"`.

Fill in the gaps to complete this function.

```py
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number=' '
  street_name=" "

  # Separate the address string into parts
  x=address_string.split(" ")
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for y in x:
    if(y.isdigit()):
      house_number=y
    else:
      street_name+=y
      street_name+=' '
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
 # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"
```

But it is showing output as :

```
house number 123 on street named  
house number 1001 on street named  
house number 55 on street named
```

Comment: @TomServo I thought with the `{}` syntax it'll just fill it left to right

Answer (score 12):

When you use `str.split()`, you have the option to choose how many segments you want to split the string to *(as long as it's not over the maximum)*. In your case, the string should only be split once, to separate the house number from the street name. Also, you can a formatted string:

```
def format_address(address_string):
    num, st = address_string.split(' ',1)
    return f"house number {num} on street named {st}"

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
```

Output:

```
house number 123 on street named Main Street
```

Comment: Very nice answer, and goes beyond just fixing the obvious bug directly.

Answer (score 4):

it looks to me like your `return` statement happens inside the `for` loop, which means you are exiting the loop after just the first item! But by that time you haven't identified the street name yet.

Just move the `return ...` back a tab and it should work fine.

Comment: Good spot!  This is a good example of why keeping your comments lined up with the code they comment is good practice; it's really hard to visually follow the vertical line of the indentation because the comments are all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number = 0
  street_name = []
  # Separate the address string into parts
  address = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for item in address:
    if item.isnumeric():
      house_number = item
    else:
      street_name.append(item)
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name

  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, " ".join(street_name))

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  number = ''
  street = ''
  # Separate the address string into parts
  address_string = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for add in address_string:
      # Determine if the address part is the
      # house number or part of the street name
      if add.isdigit():
          number += add 
      # Does anything else need to be done 
      # before returning the result?
      else :
          street += " " + add
      # Return the formatted string  
      return "house number {} on street named {}".format(number, street)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def format_address(address_string):
# Declare variables
house_number=''
street_name=''
# Separate the address string into parts
address = address_string.split()
# Traverse through the address parts
for add in address:
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
    if add.isnumeric():
        house_number = int(add)
    else:
        street_name += add + " "
        # Does anything else need to be done 
        # before returning the result?
    # Return the formatted string
return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name.strip())
```

Comment: Hi Ghyxen. Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also, there are a lot of answers for this question. Can you please explain why I should use this one rather than one of the existing answers. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Actually managed to get it...right? without external help, but it didn´t pass because the function prints a space after every element, so for example it showed  "house number 123 on street named Main Street ", so i tried to fix it:

```
def format_address(address_string):
    # Declare variables
    house_number=""
    street_name=""
    lista=address_string.split()
    # Separate the address string into parts
    # Traverse through the address parts
    for x in lista:
        if x.upper()==x.lower(): #didn´t know about .isdigit() at the time 
        house_number=x
    elif x==lista[-1]:  #takes the space out if it is the last element of the list
        street_name+=x
    else:
        street_name+=x+" "
        # Determine if the address part is the
        # house number or part of the street name
        # Does anything else need to be done 
        # before returning the result?
        # Return the formatted string  
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"
```

Answer (score 1):

used isnumeric() to separate house number and street name.

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house = ""
  street = ""
  # Separate the address string into parts
  words = address_string.split()
  
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for item in words:
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
    if item.isnumeric():
      house = item
    else:
      street = street + " " + item
  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named{}".format(house, street)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your return is not in the good indentation. It's called in the first loop so your boucle for did just one iteration.

````
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number=' '
  street_name=" "

  # Separate the address string into parts
  x=address_string.split(" ")
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for y in x:
    if(y.isdigit()):
      house_number=y
    else:
      street_name+=y
      street_name+=' '
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
 # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?

  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do this!

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  space = address_string.find(" ")
  house_number = address_string[:space]
  street_name = address_string[space:]
  return "house number {} on street named{}".format(house_number, street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  house_number =''
  street_name =''

  # Declare variables

  # Separate the address string into parts
  spi = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for ele in spi:
    if ele.isdigit():
      house_number = ele
    else:
      street_name += ele
      street_name += ' '
`

`# Return the formatted string`
  `return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, street_name)`


print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"`
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
def format_address(address_string):
    # Declare variables
    hn =""
    ha =""
  # Separate the address string into parts
    address_string = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
    for add in address_string:
        if add.isnumeric():
            hn += add
        else:
            ha += add + " "
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
  # Does anything else need to be done
  # before returning the result?

  # Return the formatted string
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(hn,ha)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
# Declare variables
  house_number=[]
  street_name=[]
  addresses=[]
# Separate the address string into parts
  addresses = address_string.split()
# Traverse through the address parts
  for address in addresses:
# Determine if the address part is the house number or part of the street name
    
    if address.isnumeric() == True:
       house_number.append(address)
    else:
       street_name.append(address)
  
  house=" ".join(house_number)
  street=" ".join(street_name)
# Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house,street)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  words = address_string.split()
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(words[0],' '.join(words[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  addres_list = []
  name = " "
  # Separate the address string into parts
  addres_list = address_string.split(" ")
  # Traverse through the address parts
  number = addres_list[0]
  name = name.join(addres_list[1:])
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(number,name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):

  address = address_string.split(" ",1)
  house=address[0]
  street=address[1]
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house,street)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

***I solve it without using if statement for numeric , i splits the list to 2 parts and add each part to the appropriate variable.***

```
def format_address(address_string):
      house_number = ''
      street_name = ''
      parts = address_string.split(' ',1)
      house_number += parts[0]
      street_name += parts[1]
    
    
      return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def format_address(address_string):
     # Declare variables
     house_number =' '
     street_name =" "

     # Separate the address string into parts
     x= address_string.split(" ")
      # Traverse through the address parts
      for y in x:
        if(y.isdigit()):
          house_number=y
        else:
          street_name+=y
          street_name+=' '
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
    # Does anything else need to be done
    # before returning the result?

    # Return the formatted string
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, street_name)

    print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
    # Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

    print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
    # Should print: "house number 1001 on stre
    print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
    # Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  street_name = ""
  houseandstreet = address_string.split()
  for i in houseandstreet:
    if i.isdigit():
      house_number = i
    else:
      street_name = street_name + i +" "   
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)
```

Comment: here house_number will be single digit always

Comment: @arunna house_number is not always a single digit beacause I have used split() method in line 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'll chip in, too.
Sometimes the number isn't at the beginning, so the shortest answer here doesn't work in that case.

Here's my version:

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
    house_nr = ""
    street = ""
  # Separate the address string into parts
    addy_parts = address_string.split()
  # Traverse through the address parts
    for p in addy_parts:
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
        if p.isnumeric() and house_nr == "":
            house_nr = p
        else:
            street += p + " "
            
  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
    return "house number {} on street named {street}".format(house_nr, street = street.rstrip())

print(format_address("Main Street 123"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave Apt 20"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

It will also take into account more than 1 numeric word in the address, e.g. when an appartment number is given, or whatever silly entry a person gives.

I know this isn't part of the original question in the Google Course this Q is from, but it helps understanding how it works.

If you just want the short answer, use @Ann Zen's answer, it's nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  z = address_string.split(" ")
  house_number = z[0]
  street_name = z[1:]
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, " ".join(street_name))

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

x[0] will be the house number, while " ".join(x[1:]) will be the street name. This works because number is always first in the string.

```
def format_address(address_string):
    x = address_string.split()
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(x[0], " ".join(x[1:]))

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

def format_address(address_string):

```
return "house number {} on street named {}".format(address_string.split()[0], " ".join(address_string.split()[1:]))

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30506215)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I added street_name_raw as a list to capture the whole street address and then use join() to concatenate the words on the list.

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number = ""
  street_name = ""
  street_name_raw = []
  # Separate the address string into parts
  address = address_string.split(" ")
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for item in address:
    if item.isnumeric():
      house_number = item
    else:
      street_name_raw.append(item)
      street_name = " ".join(street_name_raw)

    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name

  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it without a for loop and just using list and string functions

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  houes_num = []
  house_add = []
  house_detail = address_string.split()
  houes_num = house_detail[0]
  house_add =  house_detail[1 : len(house_detail)]
  a = " ".join(house_add)
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(houes_num,a)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number = ""
  street_name = ""
  # Separate the address string into parts
  address = address_string.split(" ", 1)
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for part in address:
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
    if part.isdigit():
      house_number += address[0]
    else:
      street_name += address[1]
  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?

  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number, street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct, yep I know its late, but maybe ontime for someone else!

```
def format_address(address_string):


 # Declare variables
  house_number = ""
  street_name = ""
  address = []
  # Separate the address string into parts
  for y in address_string.split():
    address.append(y)
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for i in address:
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
    if i.isnumeric():
      house_number = house_number + str(i)
    else:
      street_name = street_name + i + " "
  # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  street_name = "".join(street_name)
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)

print(format_address("123 Main Street"))
# Should print: "house number 123 on street named Main Street"

print(format_address("1001 1st Ave"))
# Should print: "house number 1001 on street named 1st Ave"

print(format_address("55 North Center Drive"))
# Should print "house number 55 on street named North Center Drive"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_address(address_string):
  # Declare variables
  house_number=' '
  street_name=" "

  # Separate the address string into parts
  x=address_string.split(" ")
  # Traverse through the address parts
  for y in x:
    if(y.isdigit()):
      house_number=y
    else:
      street_name+=y
      street_name+=' '
    # Determine if the address part is the
    # house number or part of the street name
 # Does anything else need to be done 
  # before returning the result?
  
  # Return the formatted string  
    return "house number {} on street named {}".format(house_number,street_name)
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!